# log4j with JNDI using c3p0

Tags: java, jdbc, jndi, c3p0, log4j2

I am experiencing the problem with log4j using c3p0

My log4j2.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="error">
    <Appenders>
        <JDBC name="databaseAppender" tableName="ACCESS_LOGS">
            <DataSource jndiName="java:/comp/env/jdbc/dbUR" />
            <Column name="USER_DESC" pattern="%user" />
            <Column name="DATED"  isEventTimestamp="true" />
            <Column name="LOGGER" pattern="%logger" />
            <Column name="AUTH_LEVEL" pattern="%level" />            
            <Column name="REASON" pattern="%message" />            
        </JDBC>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="warn">
            <AppenderRef ref="databaseAppender"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

When I call

```
logger.error("TEST LOG");
```

I get the following error:

```
2015-02-25 12:09:49.624:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:qtp857668665-16: 
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.isClosed()Z
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:393) at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:393)
    at ...
```

What could be the issue? Any ideas?

These are the maven dependencies and their versions of log4j and c3p0:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Solved the problem downgrading log4j2 to 2.0. But why this does not work with version 2.0.2?

Comment: When c3p0 initializes, it logs a banner at INFO which includes the c3p0 version (just before it dumps config information). Please check that banner. Whatever your dependencies say, it looks like your app is finding an older version of c3p0 in its CLASSPATH,

Comment: INFO: Initializing c3p0-0.9.5

Comment: The error suggests that the `Statement.isClosed` method is not implemented (added in JDBC 4), which either means that c3p0 itself doesn't support JDBC 4 (which afaik it does), or that the JDBC driver you are using is a JDBC 3 driver, and not JDBC 4 (or 4.1, 4.2). Which JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: Absolutely. And my question is that, why it does not supported in latest version?

Comment: I don't know, the comments in [this file](https://github.com/swaldman/c3p0/blob/34e2a7f1d654952153cacfe1a7fd442fe5d8930a/src/java/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/codegen/JdbcProxyGenerator.java) seem to suggest that c3p0 doesn't actually support JDBC 4...

Comment: So, verifying with javap -c against a freshly downloaded 0.9.5 jar shows that the isClosed() method of NewProxyPreparedStatement is defined. Somewhere in your world, there must be an older version of the library around (the behavior you are seeing is the expected behavior for pre- 0.9.5 versions, which did not support newer JDBC4 methods). If you are seeing the 0.9.5 banner, there's likely an issue where the older version is loaded by some ClassLoaders, while 0.9.5 is loaded too. I'd try to search the environment for the older version.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel c3p0 fully supports JDBC4 as of c3p0 0.9.5.

Comment: @SteveWaldman Ah, ok, then probably the comments in the file I linked to weren't updated to reflect this.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel (yeah, there are shadows of 0.9.2's partial support there. I should get rid of those :)